# SQL Division after HAVING-clausel

Tags: sql, division, having

i have a sql problem. I got two tables:

```
album (asin(pk), title, artist, price, release, label, rank)
track (album(pk), dsk, posn, song)
```

I need to find cheap albums where the price per song is under $0.5. How can i filter with a divion? My attempt so far:

```
SELECT a.title,a.price,COUNT(b.song) 
FROM album a 
JOIN track b 
ON (asin=album) 
GROUP BY album 
HAVING COUNT(a.price / b.song)
```

I know that is wrong. I'm very new to SQL and it's confusing. I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT a.title, a.price, COUNT(b.song) 
    FROM album a
    JOIN track b ON asin=album 
GROUP BY a.title, a.price
  HAVING 1.0 * a.price / COUNT(b.song) < 0.5
```

The JOIN condition `asin=album` looks fishy. Fix it by adding table aliases for the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by `a.asin` (I suppose this is a unique album id, title potentially can be identical) because what you want is to group all the tracks into one line representing an album. `COUNT(*)` will count the number of rows grouped into this record (same as number of songs in the album). `HAVING` calculates average song price and tells to leave only albums cheaper than 0.5:

```
SELECT a.title, a.price, COUNT(*)
FROM album a 
JOIN track b ON b.asin=b.album 
GROUP BY a.asin
HAVING a.price / COUNT(*) < 0.5
```

Comment: `Having .. n` doesn't work in all RDBMS. `n` in the SELECT clause cannot be referenced in the HAVING clause in sql-server for example.